# how to display of a array in object on template - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I want to show the name field from my obj to the template. My object contains an array of data from the backend which have a few more field apart from the name.
response from the backend is in this formate :

```js
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "A Place for Everything",
  "slug": "a-place-for-everything",
  "image": {
    "thumbnail": "http://127.0.0.1:6902/media/__sized__/merchants/c105bd1ed954c5c465cdd22d04d7009ed4486157-thumbnail-100x100-70.jpg",
    "full_size": "http://127.0.0.1:6902/media/merchants/c105bd1ed954c5c465cdd22d04d7009ed4486157.jpg",
    "small_square_crop": "http://127.0.0.1:6902/media/__sized__/merchants/c105bd1ed954c5c465cdd22d04d7009ed4486157-crop-c0-5__0-5-50x50-70.jpg",
    "medium_square_crop": "http://127.0.0.1:6902/media/__sized__/merchants/c105bd1ed954c5c465cdd22d04d7009ed4486157-crop-c0-5__0-5-400x400-70.jpg"
  }
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "A Quarter Of",
  "slug": "a-quarter-of",
  "image": {
    "thumbnail": "http://127.0.0.1:6902/media/__sized__/merchants/5f742766e7dec63e62baaf029f3d3d7025adac36-thumbnail-100x100-70.jpg",
    "full_size": "http://127.0.0.1:6902/media/merchants/5f742766e7dec63e62baaf029f3d3d7025adac36.jpg",
    "small_square_crop": "http://127.0.0.1:6902/media/__sized__/merchants/5f742766e7dec63e62baaf029f3d3d7025adac36-crop-c0-5__0-5-50x50-70.jpg",
    "medium_square_crop": "http://127.0.0.1:6902/media/__sized__/merchants/5f742766e7dec63e62baaf029f3d3d7025adac36-crop-c0-5__0-5-400x400-70.jpg"
  }
},
```

.ts file:

```js
keys: any[] = []
merchant: any[] = []
popularMerchant: any[] = []
obj: {
  [k: string]: any
} = {
  A: [],
  B: [],
  C: [],
  D: [],
  E: [],
  F: [],
  G: [],
  H: [],
  I: [],
  J: [],
  K: [],
  L: [],
  M: [],
  N: [],
  O: [],
  P: [],
  Q: [],
  R: [],
  S: [],
  T: [],
  U: [],
  V: [],
  W: [],
  X: [],
  Y: [],
  Z: []
};



ngOnInit(): void {
  this.keys = Object.keys(this.obj)
  for (let i of this.keys) {
    this.api.getMerchantsWithAlbhabet(i).subscribe(response => {
      this.merchant.push(response.results)
      this.obj[i] = response.results;
    })
  }
  this.getPopularMerchants()
}
```

.html file

```html
<section class="dc-card stores">
  <div *ngFor="let key of keys">
    {{obj[key] | json}}
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried doing {{obj[key].name | json}} in html file but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<section class="dc-card stores mt-3">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let key of keys">
        <ng-container *ngIf="obj[key].length > 0">
                <div *ngIf="!sectionToShow || sectionToShow == key" class="card flex-row my-2">
                    <div class="key">{{key}}</div>
                    <ul class="store mt-3">

                        <ng-container *ngFor="let eachMerchant of obj[key]">
                            <li class="p-1" (click)="merchantClicked(eachMerchant)">
                                {{eachMerchant.name}}
                            </li>
                        </ng-container>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

</section>
```